# SQL File not found when running liquibase update from sqlcl

Tags: oracle, liquibase, sqlcl

The problem is simple: liquibase fails to find my changeset sqlfile to run it against my db.

Paths are as follows:

- SqlCl: `C:\Oracle\sqlcl`
- No CLASSPATH is defined in user env variables
- Main changelog file: `C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\main.yaml`
- Changeset sqlfile: `C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\test.sql`

main.yaml contains:

```
databaseChangeLog:

  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: some_author
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: test.sql
            splitStatements: true
            endDelimiter: /
            stripComments: true
```

test.sql contains:

```
create or replace view asdas
as
select 1 val from dual
/
```

What I get when I run liquibase update via sqlcl:

```
C:\repos\odb\db-scripts>sql stat_adm@dev-odb1
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en

SQLcl: Release 20.4 Production on Tue May 25 18:03:50 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Password? (**********?) ********
Last Successful login time: Tue May 25 2021 18:03:55 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0


SQL> lb update -changelog main.yaml

Processing has failed for your request.
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.io.IOException: The file test.sql was not found in
    - C:\Oracle\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\Oracle\jlib\orai18n-mapping.jar
    - C:\Oracle\jlib\orai18n-utility.jar
    - C:\Oracle\jlib\orai18n.jar
    - C:\Oracle\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\Oracle\modules\oracle.xdk\xmlparserv2.jar
    - C:\Oracle\rdbms\jlib\xdb6.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ST4.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\antlr-runtime.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\commons-codec.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\commons-logging.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-data.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-http.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-net.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-sqlcl.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-liquibase.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-modeler-cli-ext.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-modeler-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\liquibase-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\migration-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\migration-postgres.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\snakeyaml-1.12.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\guava.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpclient.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpcore.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpmime.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-annotations.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-jr-objects.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-jr-stree.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jansi.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\javax.json.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jdbcrest.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jline.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\oraclepki.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-collation.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-mapping.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-servlet.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-utility.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orajsoda.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\osdt_cert.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\osdt_core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\slf4j-api.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\slf4j-jdk14.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-contrib.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xdb6.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xmlparserv2-sans-jaxp-services.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xmlparserv2.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\localedata.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunec.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
    - C:\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\jlib\orai18n-mapping.jar
    - C:\jlib\orai18n-utility.jar
    - C:\jlib\orai18n.jar
    - C:\rdbms\jlib\xdb6.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\ST4-4.3.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\commons-codec-1.15.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\commons-logging-1.2.0.0.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\dbtools-common-20.4.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\dbtools-data-20.4.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\dbtools-http-20.4.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\dbtools-net-20.4.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\dbtools-sqlcl-20.4.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\guava-30.0-jre.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\httpclient-4.5.13.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\httpcore-4.4.13.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\httpmime-4.5.13.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jackson-core-2.11.3.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jackson-jr-objects-2.11.3.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jackson-jr-stree-2.11.3.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jansi-1.18.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\javax.json-1.1.4.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jdbcrest-20.4.1.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\jline-2.14.6.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\low-level-api-13.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\ojdbc8-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\oraclepki-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\orai18n-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\orai18n-mapping-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\orai18n-utility-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\orajsoda-1.1.3.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\osdt_cert-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\osdt_core-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\slf4j-jdk14-1.7.30.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\sshd-common-2.5.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\sshd-contrib-2.5.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\sshd-core-2.5.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\sshd-scp-2.5.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\sshd-sftp-2.5.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\ucp-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\xdb6-21.0.0.jar
Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.

SQL>
```

Somehow it picks up `C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\` path but there are just imaginary jar that don't persist there. By the way paths `C:\jdbc\lib\`, `C:\jlib\`, `C:\rdbms\jlib\xdb6.jar` don't even exist on my machine.

Adding `relativeToChangelogFile: true` to `main.yaml` doesn't help.

How should I tell `sqlcl` to pick up `test.sql` file from the current directory or at least provide a full path?

**EDIT:**

I decided to run it using `liquibase` itself. I downloaded liquibase installation zip archive and took `liquibase.bat` from it and put it into `sqlcl` installation path. Then I added this path to my `PATH` variable so that I can call it from command line.

Also I created in `C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\` file `liquibase.properties` with the following contents:

```
changeLogFile: main.yaml
driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@mega-db-host:1521/odb1
username: usr
password: pwd
```

Note that `C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\` is the same dir for `test.sql` and `main.yaml`. After that I've run liquibase:

```
C:\repos\odb\db-scripts>liquibase update
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ##
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##  Get advanced features and support at          ##
##      liquibase.com/support                     ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 10:11:50 (version 4.1.1 #0 built at 2020-11-02 16:02+0000)
ScriptRunner Executing: create or replace view asdas
as
select 1 val from dualLiquibase Executed:create or replace view asdas
as
select 1 val from dual
Liquibase: Update has been successful.
```

See: no errors. After that I decided to set non-existing path to sql file and guess what I've got:

```
C:\repos\odb\db-scripts>liquibase update
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ##
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##  Get advanced features and support at          ##
##      liquibase.com/support                     ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 10:12:44 (version 4.1.1 #0 built at 2020-11-02 16:02+0000)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.io.IOException: The file not_exists.sql was not found in
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ST4.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\antlr-runtime.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\commons-codec.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\commons-logging.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-data.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-http.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-net.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-sqlcl.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-liquibase.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-modeler-cli-ext.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-modeler-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\liquibase-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\migration-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\migration-postgres.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\snakeyaml-1.12.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\guava.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpclient.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpcore.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpmime.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-annotations.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-jr-objects.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-jr-stree.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jansi.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\javax.activation-api.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\javax.json.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jaxb-api.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jdbcrest.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jline.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\low-level-api.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\oraclepki.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-mapping.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-utility.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orajsoda.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\osdt_cert.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\osdt_core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\slf4j-api.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\slf4j-jdk14.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\snakeyaml-1.12.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-contrib.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-scp.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-sftp.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ucp.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xdb6.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xmlparserv2-sans-jaxp-services.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\localedata.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunec.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts
    - C:\repos\odb\db-scripts\.
Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

Note that liquibase added the current directory on the lookup list. And that's why it managed to find my `test.sql` file. Looks like `sqlcl` is the one who fails to use the current path for SQL files.

Comment: we don't have support for relative file paths yet (coming in next release) - i think you need to have that file in the same directory you've launched sqlcl from or you need the absolutely path in your changelog for the script your'e going to run

Comment: @thatjeffsmith please see my edits to the question. Looks like `liquibase` does his stuff properly, while `sqlcl` fails to add a current path on the lookup list for sql files.