# sqlcl can't perform liquibase update for a simple changelog

Tags: oracle, liquibase, sqlcl

I'm really stuck on the simpliest example of liquibase migration taken from [Oracle-Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-automating-your-database-deployments-using-sqlcl-and-liquibase). So I've created two files and put it into folder `preset`.

Contents of file `controller.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.9.xsd">
    <changeSet author="tim" id="01_tab1_seq">
      <sqlFile dbms="oracle"
               endDelimiter=";"
               path="test.sql"
               splitStatements="true"
               relativeToChangelogFile="true"
               stripComments="false"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Contents of file `test.sql`:

```
create or replace view asdas
as
select 1 val from dual
/
```

I open Windows Terminal Preview at this folder and try to perform a migration:

```
PS C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset> sql testuser/testuser@dev-db1
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en

SQLcl: Release 21.1 Production on Tue Jul 20 18:25:55 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Jul 20 2021 18:25:57 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0


SQL> lb update -changelog controller.xml

Processing has failed for your request.
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.io.IOException: The file test.sql was not found in
    - C:\Oracle\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\Oracle\jlib\orai18n-mapping.jar
    - C:\Oracle\jlib\orai18n-utility.jar
    - C:\Oracle\jlib\orai18n.jar
    - C:\Oracle\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\Oracle\modules\oracle.xdk\xmlparserv2.jar
    - C:\Oracle\modules\org.glassfish.javax.json.jar
    - C:\Oracle\rdbms\jlib\xdb6.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ST4.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\antlr-runtime.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\commons-codec.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\commons-logging.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-data.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-http.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-net.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\dbtools-sqlcl.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-liquibase.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-modeler-cli-ext.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\dbtools-modeler-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\liquibase-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ext\snakeyaml-1.12.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\guava.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpclient5.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpcore5.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\httpmime.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-annotations.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-jr-objects.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jackson-jr-stree.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jansi.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\javax.json.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jdbcrest.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\jline.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\oraclepki.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-collation.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-mapping.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-servlet.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n-utility.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orai18n.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\orajsoda.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\osdt_cert.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\osdt_core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\slf4j-api.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\slf4j-jdk14.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-common.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-contrib.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\sshd-core.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xdb6.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xmlparserv2-sans-jaxp-services.jar
    - C:\Oracle\sqlcl\lib\xmlparserv2.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\localedata.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\sunec.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\ST4-4.3.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\commons-codec-1.15.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\commons-logging-1.2.0.0.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\dbtools-common-21.1.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\dbtools-data-21.1.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\dbtools-http-21.1.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\dbtools-net-21.1.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\dbtools-sqlcl-21.1.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\guava-30.1-jre.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\httpclient5-5.0.3.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\httpcore5-5.0.3.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jackson-annotations-2.12.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jackson-core-2.12.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jackson-jr-objects-2.12.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jackson-jr-stree-2.12.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jansi-1.18.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\javax.json-1.1.4.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jdbcrest-21.1.1.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\jline-2.14.6.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\low-level-api-13.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\ojdbc8-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\oraclepki-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\orai18n-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\orai18n-mapping-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\orai18n-utility-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\orajsoda-1.1.6.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\osdt_cert-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\osdt_core-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\slf4j-jdk14-1.7.30.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\sshd-common-2.6.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\sshd-contrib-2.6.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\sshd-core-2.6.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\sshd-scp-2.6.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\sshd-sftp-2.6.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\ucp-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\xdb6-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\xmlparserv2-sans-jaxp-services-21.0.0.jar
    - C:\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar
    - C:\jlib\orai18n-mapping.jar
    - C:\jlib\orai18n-utility.jar
    - C:\jlib\orai18n.jar
    - C:\rdbms\jlib\xdb6.jar
Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
```

Even though I'm running `sqlcl` from the same directory I get the error above. One can see that directory `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset\` is not on the list. Instead there is a bunch of `jar` files that don't persist in this directory.

My OS version is Windows 10. Here's versions of tools I use:

```
PS C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\preset> sql testuser/testuser@dev-db1
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en

SQLcl: Release 21.1 Production on Tue Jul 20 18:35:55 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Jul 20 2021 18:35:57 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0


SQL> lb version


Liquibase version:   4.3.1
Extension Version:   21.1.1.0
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to run it using Windows 10 Linux Subsystem and it worked:

```
roman@UBUNTU-LT:/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/Desktop/preset$ sql testuser/testuser@dev-db1

SQLcl: Release 21.1 Production on Thu Jul 22 16:54:14 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Thu Jul 22 2021 16:54:18 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0


SQL> lb update -changelog controller.xml

######## ERROR SUMMARY ##################
Errors encountered:0

SQL>
```

Looks like there's something with running it under Windows environment.

Comment: it can't find the file for some reason (i think that's liquibase code, not ours?) does it work if you put an explicit file path instead?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith please see the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67690838/sql-file-not-found-when-running-liquibase-update-from-sqlcl?noredirect=1#comment119648657_67690838 I tried it with `liquibase` itself and it worked. And full path doesn't work either because Liquibase restricted this after 4.0 version (you can see this message on the bottom of the biggest code block in the question)